# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when applying datetime

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime, hash

I get unhashable TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when trying to apply to datetime. The problem is that when applying iloc x is no longer from type pd. so what should I do is this case?

the column of X which is dates like 21/10/2020

```
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np


#import data

s= pd.read_csv('.....csv', header=0, squeeze=True)


x= s.iloc[:,0].values.reshape(-1,1)   
X=pd.to_datetime(x)# here is the problem
#np.atleast_2d(X)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and the content are dates

Comment: could you please be a bit more precise (dimensions, dtype of "dates" etc.) and add an example to the question?

Comment: just guessing: are you looking to parse the first column of dataframe `s` to datetime? Then just do `x = pd.to_datetime(s.iloc[:,0], dayfirst=True)`

Answer (score 0):

according to documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Parameters

```
arg:  int, float, str, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series, DataFrame/dict-like

    The object to convert to a datetime.
```

You check the shape of x in `x= s.iloc[:,0].values.reshape(-1,1)`

[image]

it's not a 1d array.

Just drop the reshape.

[image]

For data like this:

[image]

```
x= df.iloc[:,0].values
pd.to_datetime(x)
```

[image]

Comment: do you *know* the shape of the OP's input after calling `reshape` or are you *guessing* it? Can you reproduce the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`?

Comment: the input is a pandas series from the slice.

Comment: well then, can you reproduce the error?

Comment: why not simply `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`? ;-)

Comment: I don't know why it was converted to x in the first place.  The question does not say.  If the output is an numpy X, then could just do X = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).to_numpy()
Let OP try and see if this solves the problem.